# Generate clues to a puzzle so that it always has a solution

Tags: algorithms

I have come across this question in an abstract reasoning test:

[image: A figure of three rows demonstrating clues to a puzzle. Each row has an initial figure, e.g. A small white circle with a horizontal line across it, followed by a set of five dots. Each dot is either black, indicating a function attributed to that dot has been applied to the shape, or white, indicating that it hasn't. At the end of the row is a final figure e.g. A large white square with no horizontal line.]

Each of the dots do something unique to the initial shape and is consistent for that column of dots. Assuming each of the functions the dots perform are independent to each other, how would I randomly generate a question like this in a way that is always solvable?

Comment: Insisting on *randomly*, generate & check for exactly one solution. Otherwise, *construct*.

Comment: Start from a valid solution and go "backward" (picking a function and applying it in reverse). If the functions are independent you should have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense these questions are never solvable, because the problem is ill-defined.  There always exists multiple candidate solutions that are consistent with the information provided.  As such, a mathematician who is being pedantic might say these types of questions are lame.

Let me give you an analogy.  I'm thinking of a sequence of integers that begins with 1, 2, 3, 4.  What is the next number in the sequence?

If you said 5, then nope, you are wrong, that is not the next number I was thinking.  Actually, I was thinking of the [Ulam numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_number), so the next number is 6, not 5.

Of course that question was silly.  And for the same reason, the question you list is silly in the same way.  It is possible to come up with multiple sets of geometric transforms that are consistent with the conditions in the "Base screen", but that lead to a different answer for "Question 1".  Now some of those transforms might look rather convoluted or non-trivial, so maybe you would consider them unlikely or implausible, but to make that systematic, you need to have an assumption on what set of transformations are allowed, or a prior on which ones are likely -- and none of that is specified in the question.

So, the pedantic answer to your question is: you can't randomly generate a question like this in a way that is always solvable, because such questions are never solvable -- there are always multiple valid solutions.

---

I suspect you won't be happy with that answer.  So, I'm going to give you an alternate approach that is an attempt to do something of the sort you're mentioning.  But realize that it has limitations, because of the above discussion.  One reasonable approach would be to start with a universe $U$ of allowed geometric transforms.  You'll have to pick that universe: maybe it includes flipping the image left-right, flipping the image up-down, zooming in, zooming out, adding a horizontal line between the left-most and right-most points in the image, and so on -- you pick what's allowable.  Now, generate a random candidate question by randomly picking a mapping from each dot to an element of $U$, and then randomly picking the "base screen" and "question 1".  In other words, randomly generate the original figures, in each row randomly generate the on-off patterns for the dots, and compute the associated "final figures" for the "base screen".  This will ensure that there exists at least one valid solution.  Now, check that the solution is unique by exhaustively enumerating all possible mappings from the dots to elements of $U$, testing which ones are consistent with the "base screen", and for ones that are consistent with the base screen, computing the answer to "question 1".  If there exists more than one valid answer to "question 1", then discard all of your choices and start over again.